# Was Zinedine Zidane ever caught offside?

Tags: football, trivia, officiating

Many sources claim that [Zinedine Zidane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinedine_Zidane) was never caught offside in his professional career.

Is this true? Because, I found two links that says: "Zidane was offside."

- http://youtu.be/2Zxi6k0oyFw

That video says "Zidane was offside" it is completly referees fault. It's not offside.

- [This](http://www.guardian.co.uk/football/1999/apr/21/newsstory.sport6) link says: Zidane was caught offside in minutes 42 and 56.

> Zidane caught offside when clean through on Schmeichel's goal. Replay suggests a bad decision (42).
>
> Zidane caught narrowly offside on the Italian's left flank. Yorke wins another long ball in the air but the attack comes to nothing (56).

But I don't feel satisfied.

Comment: I really don't see why there should be a zinedine-zidane tag.. Should we have a tag for every good player in all sports that are on-topic here?

Comment: There is a similar question [on quora](http://www.quora.com/Zinedine-Zidane/Was-Zinedine-Zidane-ever-caught-offside-in-his-professional-career).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Was Zinedine Zidane ever caught offside?

The answer is of course **Yes**.

You answered your own question, Zidane was caught offside in Juventus 2 - 3 Man United match.
And your youtube link shows it clearly that he was caught offside during 2006 World-cup, It doesn't matter if it was right or wrong decision!

In addition to your links he also caught offside during Barcelona 3-0 win over Real Madrid on November 19, 2005 - [Link](http://soccernet.espn.go.com/gamecast?id=188521&cc=5739).

> 81' Zinedine Zidane (Real Madrid) is caught offside